# How snap PlayHead to start or end of strip in NLA Editor?

Tags: animation, edit-mode, timeline, nla-editor

How snap PlayHead to start or end of strip in NLA Editor?

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Using <kbd>PgUp</kbd> and <kbd>PgDn</kbd> will cycle through the beginning and end of strips.

Comment: This not working. I have unchanged hotkeys, I looked in the settings what is assigned to "page up" and "page down". There are only two commands that have nothing to do with working with the timeline.

Comment: Sorry, I was thinking of the video editor. I don't think there's a way to snap the playhead, but if you select the strip and press the Numpad . , it will focus on the current strip and you can click the start of the clip